# I'm getting duplicate traces using Serilog's Application Insight's sink and Application Insights SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights, serilog

I'm getting duplicate traces when using Serilog's Application Insight's sink and Application Insights SDK.

The following is my Serilog's configuration in appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=9edfafc1-8526-461b-95b4-aee1f72291d7;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.EventTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithProcessId",
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }
```

Inside the Program.cs:

```
               .UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                }, writeToProviders: true
                )
```

Inside the Startup.cs:

```
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(o =>
                {
                    o.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
                });
```

[Duplicate traces example. The Custom Event one is coming from Serilog, the other one from the SDK I guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vmTL.png)

Comment: Removing the ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider did the trick:
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1310#issuecomment-870720510